How can I add a new validation rule without impacting other and parent fields?
I have a class PojoB which contains a field code and a field of class PojoA:
@Data
public class PojoB {

    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @NotBlank()
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+")
    private String code;
    
    @Valid
    private PojoA pojoA;
    
}

@Data
public class PojoA {

    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @NotBlank()
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+")
    private String code;
}


And PojoB is used as a request body of /testSpringValidation1, validations are enabled.
Now regarding the new API /testSpringValidation2, the pojoA.code can allow more characteres and no change/difference on other validation rules comparing /testSpringValidation1. So @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9a-z]+", groups = LessValidation.class) is added. But how can I implement it without changing exisitng code?
public interface LessValidation extends Default {
}

    @PostMapping("/testSpringValidation2")
    public PojoB testSpringValidation2(@RequestBody @Validated({LessValidation.class}) PojoB reqBody) {
        return reqBody;
    }

@Data
public class PojoA {

    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @NotBlank()
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9a-z]+", groups = LessValidation.class)
    private String code;
}

When triggering /testSpringValidation2 API by this reqbody,
{
    "code":"12345",
    "pojoA":{
        "code": "12ab"
    }
}

I received this error
error:
{
    "type": "error",
    "code": "400",
    "details": "mandatory parameter pojoA.code is invalid: must match \"[0-9]+\""
}

But if I don't make LessValidation extend Default, then other validation rules (like validations on pojoB.code) will also be skipped.

I think this validation '@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+")' is forced in all cases due to not being grouped. You can try to create a separate group for it and try.

What makes you think that changes the validation rules of PojoA impact those on PojoB? afaik validations without a group apply to all the groups. So you would need to update those to have a group as well and determine what belongs to what. Or just create new Pojos for the new endpoint with new validation rules. It basically is a new contract (internally).
